# Drools sharing of static facts with multiple KieSessions

Tags: java, drools, jbpm, business-process-management

I am working in an application where a transaction need to be process for fraud detection against million of history transactions. I am using Drools v6.4, StatefulKnowledgeSession and only one KnowledgeBase (i.e., one set of rule file or drl file).

Problem arises that I have 2 million static facts which I need to insert into KieSession(drools working memory). This makes processing very slow, i.e., only 50-60 transactions per minute.

I even tried to make multiple KieSessions to make it multi-threaded, which definitely speeds up the application little bit but increases the memory footprint, as I have to insert those 2 million facts into each KieSession.

So, with 2 KieSession speed increases like 100 transaction/minute but with 2 KieSession performance is almost same, i.e., 110 transaction/min. I believe this is because memory consumption.

**Is there any way I can share those static facts among multiple KieSessions? Or get those facts on demand, so that I can save the memory footprint also with increasing performance?**

Comment: Are you inserting 2 million facts onset? What keyword are you using for insertion? - _insert_ or _insertLogical_ ?

Comment: @Rupesh I am using insert as those facts are static and needed while processing rules.

Comment: @Rupesh, Problem is as the facts grow, speed/performance decreases. I am looking for a solution so that I don't have to insert those facts into the KieSession/working memory of drools. Also, can make multiple KieSessions and run them parallely to process more transactions. But I am not getting any solution to have those static facts in a common place where all KieSession can look-upon.

Comment: Working memory is that place from where KieSessions can look up the facts. The problem here is that you need to populate the facts in the WM in order to fire your rules and the size of the facts grows too big. Can you try using _insertLogical_ instead of _insert_ so that unwanted facts will be removed from WM automatically and tell me if that makes it any better. Also have you been retracting the facts from WM once jobs/rules were completed?

Comment: @Rupesh, I am also deleting the Facts which I don't need further using KieSession.delete(FactHandle) method. Those 2million facts I cannot remove as they will be required by rules to fire. What I want is a way such that I don't have to put those 2 million facts in the WM, instead I can make a call to DB and only get required facts/objects for processing.